# Is it possible to edit a deleted question?

Tags: support, status-completed, editing, deleted-questions

Is it possible to edit a deleted question?

This question is its own answer.

The following text was added [by a mod](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/1623/2), [by the original author](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/1623/3), and [by another 10K+ user](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/1623/4), while the question was deleted, indicating that:

> It's possible for mods, and the original author, at least.
>
> EDIT: It turns out that it is possible to edit a deleted question.

And then the question was undeleted so more people could see the information in it.

Comment: This is the silliest meta post :)

Comment: @DoubleAA, I dunno, BH is currently using [science](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/567/208) to test deletion of accepted answers.  Using woodchucks. :-)  (Post may vanish without notice.)

Answer (score 2):

According to the text in the question, the answer is "yes; it is possible to edit a deleted quesiton."