# Unable to edit own deleted question

Tags: support, editing, deleted-questions

Based on [this](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1623/is-it-possible-to-edit-a-deleted-question), it seems like I should be able to edit my own post which I have deleted; however, I am unable to edit a post which I have deleted and want to edit before undeleting. The edit button is grayed-out and unclickable. I *do* have an undelete button which seems like it works.

[image: uneditable deleted post]

Answer (score 2):

When you move your mouse cursor over the grayed-out edit link, you should see a tooltip saying

> You cannot edit your own deleted question. Undelete before editing.

As to the reasons for this, see the comments and answer on [this question on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178760/couple-of-issues-with-roomba-turbocharging).

Comment: Does that mean that something went wrong with the meta post that I linked to in my question?

Comment: Ah, never mind. The original author is a 10k+ user.